# Changing a list fo pickle

Tags: python-3.x

i need to change my program so that it saves the list as a pickled file, however I'm not sure how to do it. iv tried reading through articles i just cant seem to figure out how to implement pickle

```
sentencelist=[]

while True:
    for word in input('Input a sentence \n').split():
        if word not in sentencelist:
            sentencelist.append(word)
        print(sentencelist.index(word) + 1, end=',')
    print()
    del sentencelist[:]
```

I understand how to use pickle i just don't know where to put it, any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
import pickle

sentencelist=[]

while True:
    for word in input('Input a sentence \n').split():
        if word not in sentencelist:
            sentencelist.append(word)
        print(sentencelist.index(word) + 1, end=',')
    print()
    del sentencelist[:]

pickle.dump(sentencelist, open('file', 'wb'))
```

Then, you can load the structure back:

```
import pickle
sentencelist = pickle.load(open('file', 'rb'))
```

Comment: it worlks as such but it prints [€]q (X   thisqX   isqX   aqX   testqe] when my input is 'this is a test'